# Editing the registry with a batch file/script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am working on editing the registry in windows 10 for deployment but nothing is working for me. I am writing a batch file that removes the Store icon from the taskbar. I found the key that needs changing but none of my attempts have been successful so far. Here is my latest attempt.

```
@echo off

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{3616E1B7-E166-433A-BBCC-03F638F02C65}User\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" /v "NoPinningStoreToTaskbar" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

I have also tried to write a powershell script but that doesn't work either. Here is the powershell script.

```
if ((Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{3616E1B7-E166-433A-BBCC-03F638F02C65}User\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer' -name NoPinningStoreToTaskbar | select -exp NoPinningStoreToTaskbar) -ne 1) {
Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{3616E1B7-E166-433A-BBCC-03F638F02C65}User\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer' -Name NoPinningStoreToTaskbar -Value 1 }
```

Any insight that you can give m would be fantastic!

Comment: What's the user context your script is running under? I guess, you'll need administrator privileges...

Comment: `Set-ItemProperty "HKCU:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" -name NoPinningStoreToTaskbar -Value 1`will create or change a registry key. you don't need any if/else for that. With admin privileges, this should work

Comment: In HKCU it should work even without admin privileges, as long as you're not trying to modify values in policy keys.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set a group policy. Instead of changing the registry, you really just want to set the enable the group policy that prevents pinning the store app to the taskbar as a part of your deployment.

1. Launch gpedit.msc -> User Configuration -> Administrative templates -> Start Menu and taskbar -> Do not allow pinning Store app to the Taskbar.
2. to test -> gpupdate /force, logoff and log back in.